# How to use mosquitto_pub to publsih the topic/message with specific time interval on the mqtt server?

Tags: mqtt

I am working on Raspberry Pi with os "Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)".Now what i am trying is to send the simple message from my raspberry pi to the mqtt server which i have created on the "api.cloudmqtt.com". I am able to send (from raspberry pi to my server) and Receive (from server to my raspberry pi)
with the following Commands

1.

```
pi@RevPi100102:~ $ mosquitto_pub -h "farmer.cloudmqtt.com" -p "18989" -u "obvrnnss" -P "xxxxxxxxx" -t "Test check" -m "Hello from RevPi"
```

2.

```
pi@RevPi100102:~ $ mosquitto_sub -h "farmer.cloudmqtt.com" -p "18989" -u "obvrnnss" -P "xxxxxxxxx" -t "Test check"
```

After this i tried to send the same message to server using the `-r` and for this i took help from [link for mosquitto_pub](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_pub-1.html)

```
pi@RevPi100102:~ $ mosquitto_pub -h "farmer.cloudmqtt.com" -p "18989" -u "obvrnnss" -P "xxxxxxxxxx" -t "Test check" -m "Hello from RevPi" -r --repeat-delay "2"

I am getting the following error,

Error: Unknown option '--repeat-delay'.
```

Can someone help me to find where i am going wrong and how to use the command `-r` and `--repeat-delay`.I am not expertise in Linux commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly the `-r` flag is not the  short version of `--repeat` or `--repeat-delay`

From the mosquitto_pub doc

> `-r,
>   --retain`
>
> If retain is given, the message will be retained as a "last known good" value on the broker. See mqtt(7) for more information.

To get repeating messages you need to use the `--repeat` flag. This can then be combined with the `--repeat-delay` flag to  set the time between each message being published.

Secondly, the repeat functionality is new, it was only added at [version 1.6](https://mosquitto.org/blog/2019/04/version-1-6-released/) of mosquitto. You not said what version you are using but if it is the default that ships with raspbian then it is unlikely you have this feature.

Comment: I upgrade the mosqutto version and now able to send the message multiple times using `--repeat`. But by using the `--repeat-delay 5-1` the server receive only once.

Comment: You have to use both `--repeat` and `--repeat-delay` to get correct effect